# Reduce navbar height when using bootstrap+ Flat UI

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, flat

I'm using designmodo's Flat UI, and I have a top bar navigation, I don't even populate it with links yet:

```html
<body>
  <nav class="navbar">
  </nav>
</body>
```

```
.navbar{
  height:18px;
  background:red;
}
```

I want to have a *really* thin topbar, like 18px. However I cannot reduce it more than 50px. What is the CSS property that I have to override?

I also tried editing manually with Chrome's DOM editor, but once I change the value, it goes back to 50ish px.

Answer (score 0):

.navbar has a minimum height on it. You need to cancel it. Add the following rule to your css

```
.navbar {
   min-height:0;
```